# getline in if statement

Tags: c++, pointers, getline

From what I've read, `getline()` used in a Boolean context returns an implicitly conversion to `void*`. I haven't found anywhere on the web any real reference to this statement. Everywhere it says that implicit conversion doesn't exist and that in a Boolean context pointers should be of the same kind (and if `ptr == 0` than `0` is converted to type of the pointer `ptr`).

Also in the standard says in a Boolean context it is converted to an unspecified-Boolean-type. What does that even mean?

Comment: "I haven't found anywhere on the web any real reference to this statement."   So you don't trust StackOverflow? :) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259269/stdgetline-returns]

Comment: unspecified-boolean-type: see [Safe Bool Idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html)

Comment: Ok from what I've read you cand define operators with any name you want like operator Bool_Type(). I thought you can't define your own operators ...

Answer (score 6):

#### In short:

It means that you can use `getline()` in a `if` statement and if it works you enter the `if` statement block.

#### In Long:

> `getline()` used in a Boolean context returns an implicitly conversion to `void*`.

The above is not technically correct (but that is the result). `getline()` actually returns a reference to the stream it was used on. When the stream is used in a Boolean context this is converted into a unspecified type (C++03) that can be used in a Boolean context. In C++11, this was updated and it is converted to `bool`.

- If the `getline()` succeeded it returns a stream in a good state. When this is converted to a `bool` **like** type it returns a non-null pointer (C++03) which when used in a Boolean context is equivalent to `true`.
- If the `getline()` fails it returns a stream in a bad state. When this is converted to a `bool` **like** type it returns a null pointer (C++03) which when used in a Boolean context is equivalent to `false`.

> I haven't found anywhere on the web any real reference to this statement.

- 21.4.8.9  Inserters and extractors **[string.io]**

  - Defines: std::istream& getline(std::istream&, std::string&)
- 27.7.2.1  Class template basic_istream **[istream]**

  - Defines: std::istream& getline(char_type* s, streamsize n);
- 27.5.5.1 Overview   **[ios.overview]**

  - Defines how a stream is converted in a boolean context

> Everywhere it says that implicit conversion doesn't exist and that in a Boolean context pointers should be of the same kind (and if `ptr == 0` than `0` is converted to type of the pointer `ptr`).

A null `void*` in a Boolean context is equivalent to `false`, any other `void*` is equivalent to `true`. (though the type is actually unspecified but you can think of it as a `void*` (just to make it easy to think about).

> Also in the standard says in a Boolean context it is converted to an unspecified-Boolean-type. What does that even mean?

It means you can use it any conditional statements:

```
if (getline())
{
     // If getline worked processes data
}

while(getline())
{
    // getline. If it works then processes then try again.
}
```

Comment: Well when I said I haven't found anywhere on the web I mean't nowhere official as in from where to this guys know this stuff ...

Comment: I still don't understand why is implicit conversion of pointers possible and in what is the pointer actually converted (in void bool or unsepcified-bool-type), I mean how does it know which one to choose.

Comment: @unknown: `I haven't found anywhere on the web` No point looking on the web. Look at the standard.

Comment: @unknown: When used in a boolean context the compiler looks for any single conversions that will convert an object into something that can be used in a boolean context. There are a couple of types that can be used in a boolean context (bool, int, pointer). So the compiler checks the object to see if there is an appropriate conversion and there is so it uses. If the compiler finds more than one choice it is a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't say it explicitly anywhere on the web because it involves putting three different facts together.

1. [`getline()` returns `istream&`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/)
2. [`istream` is convertable to `void*`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_voidpt/)
3. This conversion is used when an `istream` is used in boolean context (such as an `if` or `while` statement).

Comment: I don't understand why is it convertible to void*. I mean why not bool* or any other type. If I overload a few conversion operators for my object, which one of them is used in if ?

Comment: It's convertable to `void*` because that's the conversion operator the standard library authors decided to write. The standard library authors decided to write a `void*` rather than a `bool` conversion because `bool` can very easily get converted to `int` (and that would make a nonsensical operation like adding 1 to your `istream` typecheck, which is not what you want). They chose `void*` as opposed to any other pointer type because you can't dereference a `void*`.

Comment: If you overload several conversion operators on your object, you'll have to consult the standard to see which gets used in which circumstances. I'm not an expert when it comes to that.

Comment: The problem is I don't know exactly what to search for in the standard, I can't find anything related to any of this ...