# Why this Github project converts a string to bool?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

This is a very popular C++ project for bioinformatics on Github:

> https://github.com/jts/sga/blob/master/src/Util/ClusterReader.cpp

there is a line:

```
bool good = getline(*m_pReader, line);
```

I can't compile this line and I don't know why the author did that.

According to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/), `getline` returns a string not bool. Indeed, this is what I get while I tried to compile the project:

```
ClusterReader.cpp: In member function ‘bool 
ClusterReader::readCluster(ClusterRecord&)’:
ClusterReader.cpp:70:41: error: cannot convert ‘std::basic_istream<char>’ to ‘bool’ in initialization
 bool good = getline(*m_pReader, line);
```

Why did the C++ code convert a string to bool? How would that be possible?

Comment: No, `std::getline` returns the original stream, and a boolean typecast on a stream will return `true` if there are no errors.  What compiler are you using?  If you want to get around this, you could modify the line to `bool good = getline(*m_pReader, line).good();`

Comment: This suggests a compiler bug (including possible mismatch between compiler and library installation); what compiler and settings are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) doesn't return `std::string`, but `std::basic_istream`. For `getline(*m_pReader, line);`, it just returns `*m_pReader`.

`std::basic_istream` could be implicit converted to `bool` via [std::basic_ios::operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) (since C++11),

> Returns `true` if the stream has no errors and is ready for I/O operations. Specifically, returns `!fail()`.

<sup>Before C++11 it could be implicitly converted to `void*`, which could be converted to `bool` too.</sup>

It seems your compiler failed to perform the implicit conversion, you can use `!fail()` as a workaround, e.g.

```
bool good = !getline(*m_pReader, line).fail();
```

Answer (score 2):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204113/getline-in-if-statement).

User *Loki Astari* wrote in his answer:

> getline() actually returns a reference to the stream it was used on.
>   When the stream is used in a boolean context this is converted into a
>   unspecified type (C++03) that can be used in a boolean context. In
>   C++11 this was updated and it is converted to bool.

That means you probably do not use an up-to-date compiler (C++03 or even better C++11). If you use `g++` or `gcc`, try adding `-std=c++11` to the command.