# Why is the return value of std::getline not convertible to bool?

Tags: c++, getline, istream

When I run the below example code from [Accelerated C++](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/742586.Accelerated_C_), I get the error:

```
error: value of type 'basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' is not contextually convertible to 'bool'
    while (std::getline(in, line)) {
```

I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204113/getline-in-if-statement) answer that starting from C++11, `getline()` returns a reference to a stream which is converted to `bool` when it is used in a Boolean context. However, I can't figure out why the stream in my code is not "contextually convertible" to `bool`. Can you explain that and point me to a correct version?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include "str_helper.h"

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::map;
using std::istream;

// other code here...

map<string, vector<int> >
xref(istream& in, vector<string> find_words(const string&) = split)
{
    string line;
    int line_number = 0;
    map<string, vector<int> > ret;

    // read next line
    while (std::getline(in, line)) {
        ++line_number;

        // break the input line into words
        vector<string> words = find_words(line);

        // remember that each word occurs on the current line
        for (vector<string>::const_iterator it = words.begin(); it != words.end(); ++it)
            ret[*it].push_back(line_number);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Adding `#include <istream>` will solve the issue. What is in `str_helper.h`? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How are you building this example?

Comment: Just checking but... are you sure you compiled with `c++11` ?

Comment: It has always returned a reference to a stream. The change in C++11 was to make a stream convertible to `bool` instead of `void*`.

Comment: Building an [mre] makes the problem somewhat clearer: https://ideone.com/X1KVmS Move down an error message or two and you'll see something like  error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::basic_istream<char>’. Compiler doesn't have a complete definition of `istream`.

Comment: Why did this happen? some of the functionality in `<string>`, `std::getline` for example,  needs a reference to `istream`. But including `<iostream>` to get the full definition runs the risk of circular dependencies and it can be expensive to pull in all of `<iostream>` if all you want is `std::string`. Solution: `<string>` forward declares `std::istream` so that includers of `<string>` know `istream` exists and can carry on. General rule of thumb: Always include all of the headers you use (and nothing more). If you count on headers including other headers you can get nasty shocks later.

Comment: By reproducing that with `g++ -std=c++11` , there is an other error `error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::basic_istream<char>’`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't add `#include <istream>` to your code, so the compiler doesn't know what `istream` is and therefore it doesn't know it is convertable to `bool`.

Add `#include <istream>` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You left out the definition of `split` which makes it not compile until you add that. And I had to remove your private include for `str_helper.h`

Adding `#include <iostream>` or `istream` does seem to fix it for me.

The problem you were having was because without the explicit include, different compiler and library versions were including various pieces of partial definitions of `istream` and `getline`.

Comment: It turned out that I forgot including `istream` in the associated header file `str_helper.h`.

Comment: @chronosynclastic -- the usual rule of thumb is that every source file should `#include` the headers that **it** needs. So `#include <istream>` belongs in the source file in the question. Don't rely on indirect includes.