# Reading file into two arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, io

I'm trying to write my own vocabulary with a test for my little brother, but I have a problem when I want to read data from file into two arrays - first with English words, and second with Polish words. File looks alike

black - czarny
red - czerwony etc.

And my function:

```
void VOC::readout()
{
    fstream file;
    VOC *arr = new VOC;
    string line;
    file.open("slowka.txt");
    if(file.good())
    {
        int i=0;
        while(!file.eof())
        {
            getline(file, line);
            size_t pos = line.find(" - "); 
            int position = static_cast<int>(pos);

            file>>arr[i].en;
            file>>arr[i].pl;
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

I thought it could be a good idea to insert a line into first array until the function finds " - ", and after that insert the rest of line into second array, but I have some problems with that. Could someone help me? I know I can solve it by using std::vector but I care to do that by using arrays.

Comment: `arr` points to *one* single `VOC` object and is *not* an array. Since you don't know how many, a `std::vector` is your best option.

Comment: What are you doing with `int position = static_cast<int>(pos);`?

Comment: I thought comparing size_t with int can cause an overflow, am I wrong?

Comment: Rather than using 2 arrays, you may want to use one `std::vector` of structures that contain both words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using plain arrays, you'll first have to count the number of lines in your file and then allocate enough memory. Arrays -- unlike `std::vector` objects -- won't grow automatically but have a fixed size.

That being said, note that using `!file.eof()` is not the best way to read a stream until the end is reached. You can use the simpler

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
  // ...
}
```

idiom instead, which also takes care of error conditions. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259269/stdgetline-returns) (and corresponding answers) for more information on that.

Comment: Thanks! I just want to learn using arrays perfectly, and then move into std::vector.
Can't believe I could forget about so obvious thing like allocating memory. 
And is string::find a good idea to use it here?